# Porque o pool de conexão fecha antes de exibir os dados do SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estou tentando exibir dados do BD em uma Recycleview mas recebo o seguinte erro:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.emerson.drawer, PID: 8316
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closFed.
```

Fiz alguns testes e verifiquei que isso ocorre quando há mais de 50 resultados. Alguém sabe algo sobre esse erro?

Minha consulta:

```
from2 = new String[]{
                DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID + " AS _id",
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_EQUIPAMENTO,
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_CLIENTES_NAME,
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ACESSORIO,
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ABERTURA,
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_SITUACAO_NAME,
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_SITUACAO_COR_R,
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_SITUACAO_COR_G,
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_SITUACAO_COR_B,
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID_AMIGAVEL,
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_MARCA,
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_FOTO

        };       
 Cursor cursor = db.Select(DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + " LEFT OUTER JOIN " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_SITUACAO + " ON " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_SITUACAO + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_SITUACAO_ID + "=" + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_SITUACAO +
                                        " LEFT OUTER JOIN " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_CLIENTES + " ON " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_CLIENTES + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_CLIENTES_ID + "=" + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_CLIENTE, from2, null, null, null, null, null, null);

     int index0 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID);
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID_AMIGAVEL);
            int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_EQUIPAMENTO);
            int index3 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_MARCA);
            int index4 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_SITUACAO_NAME);
            int index5 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ACESSORIO);
            int index6 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_CLIENTES_NAME);
            int index7 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ABERTURA);
            int index8 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_SITUACAO_COR_R);
            int index9 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_SITUACAO_COR_G);
            int index10 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_SITUACAO_COR_B);
            int index11 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_FOTO);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int id = cursor.getInt(index0);
                    String numero = cursor.getString(index);
                    String equipamento = cursor.getString(index2);
                    String marca = cursor.getString(index3);
                    String situacao = cursor.getString(index4);
                    String acessorio = cursor.getString(index5);
                    String cliente = cursor.getString(index6);
                    String data = cursor.getString(index7);
                    int corR = cursor.getInt(index8);
                    int corG = cursor.getInt(index9);
                    int corB = cursor.getInt(index10);
                    byte[] ft = cursor.getBlob(index11);

                    Bitmap foto = null;
                    if (ft != null) {
                        foto = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ft, 0, ft.length);
                    }

                    OsList lista = new OsList(id, numero, equipamento, marca, situacao, acessorio, cliente, data, corR, corG, corB, foto);
                    osList.add(lista);

                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
```

DataBaseHandler.class

```
...
public Cursor Select(String tabela, String campos[], String where,
                         String[] whereArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit) {
        Cursor c = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            Log.i("response", "Iniciando consulta");
            c = db.query(tabela, campos, where, whereArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit);


        } finally {
            if (c != null)
                Log.i("teste", String.valueOf(c.getCount()));
            db.close();
        }
        return c;
    }
...
```

Comment: Verifique se você está usando o `db.close()` ou até mesmo `cursor.close()`... é interessante fechar o banco toda vez que for usado.

Comment: @AckLay O método de consulta contém `
        } finally {
            if (c != null)
                Log.i("teste", String.valueOf(c.getCount()));
            db.close();
        }
        return c;
    }`

Comment: Você consegue debugar e ver onde está parando?

Comment: `db` é uma classe do tipo SQLiteOpenHelper? Se sim, ela é Singleton? Coloque o código completo dessa consulta.

Comment: @ramaral sim é do tipo SQLiteOpenHelper, editei a pergunta, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no método `Select()`. Nele é feito o close da db e consequentemente do cursor.

Altere o método assim:

```
...
public Cursor Select(String tabela, String campos[], String where,
                     String[] whereArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit) {
    Cursor c = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.i("response", "Iniciando consulta");
    c = db.query(tabela, campos, where, whereArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit);
    return c;
}
...
```

No código que chama o método `Select()` faço o close do cursor após o ter utilizado.
Fazer o close da db não é obrigatório e até pode não ser desejado. Caso queira, quando não necessitar mais da db, chame o método `close()` da classe SQLiteOpenHelper, normalmente isso é feito no `onDestroy()`.

Comment: Amigo @ramaral funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado. o `close()` deve ser feito no fragment da consulta ou na Activity principal?

Comment: Se se refere ao close da db depende se a SQLiteOpenHelper é Singleton ou não. Se for, deve fazê-lo quando tem a certeza de que não irá mais usá-la, se não for, faça-o no local onde a instanciou. No entanto, como eu disse na resposta, não é obrigatório fazer o close da db